# NetSuite Saved Search Print Criteria Information

Tags: netsuite

I would like to be able to print the Criteria information that I used in the footer of the PDF of a Saved Search. I have tried looking at making an Advanced PDF to handle this, but I cannot find the field to pull in the criteria information into either the Saved Search or the Advanced PDF. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I have created a Saved Search in NetSuite that displays all of the Inventory Receipts made the previous week. We have to print this Saved Search and check it against the actual paper receipts to verify counts and receipts. When the Saved Search prints to PDF it does not show the criteria information for which the Saved Search was run to prove to Internal Audit that we have run this report for the correct dates. I would like a way to print the Criteria information for this Saved Search along with a timestamp of when the Saved Search was run and the users that ran the Saved Search. Is there a way to pull in this additional information in a Saved Search or Advanced PDF somehow?

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to pull the criteria information. If you are using suitescript though, you can build a JSON of the saved search and then use something like `JSON.stringify` to put it on the PDF. Comment back if you need an example.

Comment: @zerecees an example would be great. I tried doing research as to not bother you, but I think that my skills are not good enough yet to really know where to start.

Comment: Don’t worry about bothering me (or most people). We all start somewhere, especially with NetSuite. I’m happy to provide an example. Can you just edit your question with exactly what you’re asking, and what you want the PDF to look like? I see the general ask, but I need like a “I want to run this saved search, with this criteria, and I want the pdf to look like this”, kind of thing.

Comment: @zerecees I have made an edit to the original question to provide more detail.

Answer (score 0):

- add a custom Print button
- button goes to a suitlet that renders the PDF
- before you render, load the search and pass the **search.filters** in to addCustomDataSource() api of the render module

Comment: Do you have a place for me to get started on this? I am pretty new to this and mostly have been working directly with Saved Searches and haven't gotten more into the weeds.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I read your edit and comment with regard to my comment. There's three big things here.

1. I don't think you should pursue a dev route with this. You can schedule the report for automated email once a day and prove that it came from a saved search which is the same saved search every time. This will save you an infinite amount of hassle
2. Developing this as your first script is going to be hard. I'm happy to help. But when I tell you it's going to be a lot of code, I mean it. See this old post I did https://stackoverflow.com/a/61066928/11323304
3. If you still want to pursue a dev route with this (which is totally fine), start with emulating the user event code on a custom suitelet like I posted above in my answer. You're going to need `N/serverWidget/ui` `N/search` and `N/xml`. The rest is all in the UserEvent functions and global context variable.

If all this still goes well over your head. Don't sweat it. Comment back, and we'll build something step by step. But, I highly, highly, highly encourage you to check out the automated email capabilities of NetSuite before trying to develop something special.